# Dynamic background bar in echarts

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, boxplot, echarts

I have a boxplot in echarts that looks like this (taken from this example code: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=boxplot-multi):

[Existing working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pULXH.png)

I am looking to adding a background bar chart for each category of each class. Let's call it a target. I just tried editing the image to show how am imagining it will look like (on category 0):

[How I wished it looked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFUte.png).

The target value should show up in the tooltip as well.

I have looked into bar charts with multiple series and even stacked bar charts. But all the options seems to be either multiple bars side-by-side or stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want but I tried overlaying boxplots and bars. [This](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=boxplot-multi&code=PTAEHEFMDtIJwIYBdKgCbIQOgFADMBXaAYyQEsB7aUAWwQGtIARTACgEpQBvHUUAG0hJ0mUAF5QAbQC6Abl6g8FOKFaDhZcaAAMs0JoA8oAIwAOPWQDUlzjz591oYslQSZ8-4uWrHAKy26oP5GxtqBvta2Cp7OKFgADgQAzgAWrACyyClYiNBoFDQcoABUoABMYewe9gC-0SJI2ImprLGQVQp1fHBCBHDUGI3ydTjEVEnCAEYIcCyNWu743mpC-gEWoCHm-pHcCtOzmAnJacYA7NodI2PQEw0I2lp0jHMIHPI3d4MIxk8MzGwOp9hN8yn8XoD5BR4uQqFo7KByEhBAAuPaeFAADyQaIA5OkCPxyPFBKAAMIuADmyjIkCSuIANPVBHgcaBccQYCg4LjOky-N8kkI0ZJ6gjPEkKH1OWjvtp6jV-fZxfZJdLILLMMYFUq-Cq-Gq4DL7mUdWL6nw8HACq8hUgAJJ5SCYtHaXX2JC5JJKOA0NFcREAT3iGvZkwomJJFCQuNAXVq7v1imtNFtQkdaGdaOM7r4noQtx9fu4QZDePDkf40dj8b4ivNnktKbTDqdLvKucRXqL_tLodxFajMbjCoU0iVgkpMDQ_vqSGheNCAFJeXWlfOKESyPFZxi4GRKVO4HiyCgaIz6ghMWQkgAFChkaDc3eNpDB_upBD5ADuq9qfIUSl9xndF7BZNlcWXC8MQXdkKhXd190pFIIKg91wyQedi0ggBWFcAL4TEAEFrySEUVTfMt2Taak4EDaDVRJU8iJ6BAXwlFIKG_NFPQISAzQlJikAAGUfUMk1SLi0TwBB-CFUc1wUCj3zxGjlHo91JO4xRZKFJUanHBRAxIm92L7PEADdZL4hi-GgBAaH7AA1azIFs2hHzRABaAAWMJ3TodsADZ_PqJIhJYyA2NAjipJ0uT-M8eN6wFTAAC0KAKEUG1fFT2UfJIyEzdyDUaOA2TdC1QGnNEKgE5Uqq0ni4D4ztKI_fgivgErEVg3EAE5tAQqriNIjMsykbRDMbUAJhmCrOxq8p5SSsclSFfc6Wyzwk3sxzVKpdTtB69rywjIcesFdM2zRABmeq9Sqvb-zUujjBOvKB3OqsY07K7W0zdsfIemL7Geg6UFowMyg-qivsras_swO1xvbHCQaTU6wxmHrRpvVHsyRxo0QOV53RShqZqxgccc7PGkgJkwiei0nMAxqrqYOXGTIZm6maq74SZmMmqoOcAEB3dkQuG1a-GkHAalkIA) is as far as I could get using [`barGap`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.barGap) and a second invisable `xAxis`. You can use the [tooltip formatter function](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip.formatter) to adjust the tooltip if you need.